# Hints to solve $\lim_{x \to 0^+}{\frac{\sqrt x +\tan^3x+\sqrt x\sin^2x}{x+x^2\cos x-\tan^2x}}$ without L'Hopital

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}{\frac{\sqrt x +\tan^3x+\sqrt x\sin^2x}{x+x^2\cos x-\tan^2x}}.$$

I tried divide both terms by $x^2$ but I didn't get anywhere doing this. Can someone give me some hints on how to solve this limit?

Comment: $\sin x \sim x, \tan x \sim x [x \to 0^+]$, etc.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\frac{\sqrt x +\tan^3x+\sqrt x\sin^2x}{x+x^2\cos x-\tan^2x}=\frac{\sqrt x}{x}\frac{1 +\frac{\tan^3x}{\sqrt x}+\sin^2x}{1+x\cos x-\frac{\tan^2x}x}$$

Comment: is the limit = infinity?

Comment: The second part goes to 1, can you see why? So all is determined by $\frac{\sqrt x}{x}=\frac1{\sqrt x}$.

Comment: we can rewrite $tan^3x*x^{\frac{-1}{2}} $  so it goes to 0 and we should be able to do the same for $tan^2x*x^-1$ and so it also goes to 0 right?

Comment: We have that $$\frac{\tan^3x}{\sqrt x}=\frac{\tan^3x}{x^3}\frac{x^3}{\sqrt x}\to ?$$

Comment: the first part equal 1 and the second  part equal 0 right?

Comment: @Levio Yes exactly! And so on. Well done, I think you get it now!